# Authorization token Axios sending but Express.js not receiving

Tags: express, vue.js, axios

I have a Vue app consuming Express API via Axios, trying to access an authenticated route. Including the Auth token in Postman Request header, the route yields the correct json response. However, from the Vue front end, it returns the error 404 unauthorized, no token found.

here are the request headers:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/groups
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: [::1]:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2587
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 14 Sep 2019 21:47:42 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/groups
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
token: Token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InVzZXJ0d29AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWQiOjIsImV4cCI6MTU3MzY4NTI0NiwiaWF0IjoxNTY4NDk3NjQ2fQ.6zDOfTQzf4KW5ry4mJFaLXnUL7wAnHP_8W0B0JEW5DA
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```

Here is the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at middleware (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:76:21)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.handle (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at jsonParser (/Users/dariusgoore/development/writerboard/writerboard-express-api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:110:7)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Base config for Axios (the console.log statement retrieves the correct result):

```
import axios from 'axios'
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
console.log('this is the token from localStorage ls', token)

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      token: token,
    },
    validateStatus: function () {
      return true;
    }
  })
}
```

Here is my cors config in Express server:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()

...

var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Here is the authentication middleware that should retrieve the token (but per the console log is getting 'undefined'):

```
const jwt = require('express-jwt');

const getTokenFromHeaders = (req) => {
  const { headers: { authorization } } = req;
  console.log('this is the authorization token from the header: ', authorization);

  if(authorization && authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Token') {
    return authorization.split(' ')[1];
  }
  return null;

};

const auth = {
  required: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    userProperty: 'user',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
  }),
  optional: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    userProperty: 'user',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
    credentialsRequired: false,
  }),
};

module.exports = auth;
```

here is the express route I am trying to secure:

```
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('../middlewares/authenticate');
const User = require('../models/User');
const knex = User.knex();

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', auth.required, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('this is the req.user from /groups', req.user);
  const userId = req.user.id

  let results = await knex.raw(`SELECT users.id, users.username, groups.id, groups.name FROM users JOIN memberships ON users.id = memberships.users_id JOIN groups ON memberships.groups_id = groups.id WHERE users.id = ${userId}`);
  console.log(results);
  res.json(results.rows);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server has this:

```js
const { headers: { authorization } } = req;
```

That appears to be looking for a header called `authorization`.

Your request has this:

```
token: Token eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1...
```

due to this:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  token: token,
},
```

That header is called `token`, not `authorization`.